# loop mysql results in php outside of mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

i am having a bit of issue with a mysql query. for some reason i can echo all all associated rows inside of the mysql query but outside of the query it only return the last row. here is my code. any suggestions?

```
//Get all associated
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ACCOUNT` WHERE ACCOUNT_ID='$act_id'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){ 

   $act_name=$row['ACT_NAME'];

   echo "$act_name<br>"; // This returns all rows fine
}

echo "$act_name<br>"; // This only return the last row. i would like to get all rows.
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: strange what you say, this can not work as you said: echo "$act_name<br>";

Comment: Inside your loop you are touching each row once, and dumping it out to the screen with the same variable ($act_name) one at a time. This variable gets a new value assigned to it every time the loop touches it (once for each entry in the array returned by the SQL ($q). If you want to echo each row, the right way to do it is inside the loop. If you want to use the data after the call, you should push it into a new array so that all the entries are maintained and usable.

Comment: you are assigning the variable `$act_name` with each row (only that one row), and then after the `while` loop runs you want to echo it. of course it only shows the last row.

Comment: Thanks all. i fixed my statement. i am good to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that you can fetch all of the records is by using [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli). Here is an example:

```
$conn =  new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `ACCOUNT` WHERE ACCOUNT_ID='$act_id'";
$results = $conn->query($query);
$resultArray = $results->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

As @esqew said, you need to stop using the `mysql_*` functions.